# Windows Firewall and IIS permission

Tags: windows

I have a website running on IIS. I have set inbound rule for wp3wp.exe with any port option, but web site is not reachable with this rule.

When I add rule with settings: **Program and Services >**

```
All programs that meet the specified conditions
```

or

```
This program: System
```

Then IIS works as expected. These firewall rules contain security vulnerabilities as I see logs.

Isn't there a rule to ensure that Firewall only communicates with IIS? Hopefully, we don't no need to check All programs that meet the specified conditions or give permission for System.

**Any suggestion?**

Answer (score -1):

A firewall can never contain vulnerabilities. IiS serves websites on port 80 and 443, so you could create a firewall rule to allow port 80,443 instead of the w3wp process.

Comment: Well, I am creating a rule for IIS but can't reach websites with w3wp.exe exception. Of course, access to the System is provided by granting permission as above. What is your advice? I wanted to share the problem with you in case there was something I didn't understand.

Comment: I have only one rule to test for incoming bounds. There is no conflict

Comment: Here is a PowerShell command how i would create the rules: `New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "HTTP" -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 80 -Action Allow; New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "HTTPS" -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 443 -Action Allow; Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "HTTP", "HTTPS" ` (if  IIS running on the same server)